# How do I find the decomposition of a string?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I need to create an algorithm for `String` decomposition.

Some examples:

- `ABCABCDEDEDEF` --> `ABC*2+DE*3+F`
- `ABCcABCczcz` --> `ABC*2+cz*2+c`
- `test` --> `test`

Each segment of the string should be seperated by a `+` and, if repeated, followed up by a `*` plus the number of times it appears in succession.

This is what I have tried:

```
private static int[] prefixFunction(String source) {
    int n = source.length();
    int[] pi = new int[n];

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int j = pi[i - 1];

        while (j > 0 && source.charAt(i) != source.charAt(j))
            j = pi[j - 1];

        if (source.charAt(i) == source.charAt(j))
            j++;

        pi[i] = j;
    }

    return pi;
}
```

Comment: nested okay? i.e. (ABC * 2 + DEF) * 3

Comment: I think no, because in this problem i need to build the most economical representation of input string using only `+` and `*` operations on string without any brackets.

Comment: What do you mean with "takes up the least space"? Is the string always sequential like this `DE`, `ABC`, etc.? Some extra examples would be good.

Comment: @Daniel "takes up the least space" = the most optimal solution. Also, add additional example.

Comment: @SlandShow - the order does not matter, right? For `test` the valid output is i.e. `sett` as well?

Comment: @SlandShow - also its unclear what you mean by "least space". Beause these two in your example `ABC*2+cz*2+c*1`/`ABC*2+c*3+z*2` has different string length. Does the space mean "number of terms", which is in those two examples `3`?

Comment: @libik sorry it was mismatch, question is updated.

I think order is matters.

Comment: @SlandShow - I think there is still issue, do you realize that `ABCcABCczcz` has 11 characters while `ABC*2+cz*2+c` has 12 characters, which emans its basically same as with `test`, the modification is not worth it.

Comment: Why is there a `c` at the end of the decomposition in your example, `ABCcABCczcz --> ABC*2+cz*2+c` ? If order matters, the last letter is a `z`, no?

Comment: What is the size of the alphabet and what kind of data do you expect? (For example, very cyclical and formed vs random, how long are the strings?)

Answer (score 2):

This solution keeps everything in order, meaning an input like `ABCABCDEDEDEF` will return `ABC*2+DE*3+F` or an input like `abDEDEab` will return `ab+DE*2+ab`.

If you don't keep the order, it will be impossible to reconstruct the `String` later with 100 % accuracy.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "ABCABCDEDEDEF";

    String output = findDecomposition(input);
    System.out.println("Output: " + output);
}

public static String findDecomposition(String input) {
    String substring = input;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int start = 0, count = 1; start < input.length(); start++, count = 1) {
        for (int end = start + 1; end < input.length(); end++) {
            substring = input.substring(start, end);

            while (true) {
                String next = input.substring(start + substring.length(), Math.min(end + substring.length(), input.length()));

                if (next.equals(substring)) {
                    count++;
                    start += substring.length();
                    end += substring.length();
                } else
                    break;
            }

            if (count > 1) {
                start += substring.length() - 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (count > 1) {
            if (builder.length() > 0 && builder.charAt(builder.length() - 1) != '+')
                builder.append('+');

            builder.append(substring + "*" + count + "+");
        } else
            builder.append(input.charAt(start));
    }

    String result = builder.toString();
    if (result.endsWith("+"))
        return result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
    else
        return result;
}
```

Comment: After a quick read this feels like what I was thinking too: a sliding window approach could be the only way to preserve the order. +1

Comment: Being able to reconstruct the string with 100% accuracy is not one of the stated requirements, and using this constraint can result in wildly different results from methods that don't address this constraint.

Comment: @גלעדברקן That is correct. However, I felt like pointing out the advantage of this approach anyways. Also, I am aware that this method's results differ from others. If OP doesn't want the order to be preserved, they can just choose another answer.

Comment: `abDEDE` is a shorter string than `ab+DE*2`, not to mention that that whole example would be shorter as a single block.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes, that problem has already been stated in the comments under the question directly and applies to this whole system in general. Still there might be some other reason OP needs it and I just delivered a working answer.

Comment: What criteria does your algorithm use if not the shortest representation? Does it pick sections to repeat at random?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212645/discussion-between-schred-and--).

Answer (score 0):

THe brute force alghoritm can work as follows.

Prerequisities:

- First letter is set as root
- Data structure of each possible solution is linked list. Value of each node is text to be written.
- When outputting solution, first put to Map all text values together with number of appereances. If it appears more than once, use `*` as multiplicator

Example: One of the solution looks like this `ABC-C-ABC`, the output will be `ABC*2+C`

Solution:

1. Take next letter from input
2. New solutions are based on existing solutions. Each new solution is old solution + new letter added in one of the existing nodes or as single letter in new node.
3. Save new solutions as existing solutions.
4. Repeat from 1 until you process all letters
5. Calculate value of all solutions and select one with lowest string characters

I added example, as you can see the number of solutions are increasing quickly so it is not fully finished for all 6 letters. Each step represent the cycle from 1. to 4., you can see that in each step the previous solutions are used as base for new solutions. There are multiple new solutions created for each existing solution.

[image: brute force]

Answer (score 0):

This code returns the following compositions:

- `ABCABCDEDEDEF -> ABC*2+DE*3+F`
- `ABCcABCczcz -> ABCc*2+zcz`
- `cefABCcABCczcz -> cef+ABCc*2+zcz`

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    public class Decomposition {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Decomposition d = new Decomposition("ABCABCDEDEDEF");
            System.out.println(d.getOptimalDecomposition());// Output: ABC*2+DE*3+F

            d = new Decomposition("ABCcABCczcz");
            System.out.println(d.getOptimalDecomposition());// Output: ABCc*2+zcz

            d = new Decomposition("cefABCcABCczcz");
            System.out.println(d.getOptimalDecomposition());// Output: cef+ABCc*2+zcz
        }



        private List> decompositions;
        private String toDecompose;

        public Decomposition(String toDecompose) {
            decompositions = new ArrayList();
            this.toDecompose = toDecompose;
        }

        public String getOptimalDecomposition() {

            decompose(0, new ArrayList());

            return calculateOptimal(convertToPartsMap());
        }

        private String calculateOptimal(List> partsCount) {
            Collections.sort(partsCount, new SortDecompositions());

            StringBuilder optimal = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i  1) {
                    optimal.append("*");
                    optimal.append(pc.count);
                }

                if (i != partsCount.get(0).size() - 1) {
                    optimal.append("+");
                }
            }

            return optimal.toString();
        }

        private List> convertToPartsMap() {
            List> partsMap = new ArrayList();

            for (List parts : decompositions) {
                List partsCount = new ArrayList();

                String lastPart = null;
                int curCount = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i  parts) {

            if (nextChar == toDecompose.length()) {
                decompositions.add(parts);
                return;
            }

            char toAdd = toDecompose.charAt(nextChar);

            if (parts.isEmpty()) {
                parts.add("" + toAdd);
                decompose(nextChar + 1, parts);
            } else {

                // left
                List leftParts = parts.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());// shallow copy
                if (!leftParts.isEmpty()) {
                    int last = leftParts.size() - 1;
                    leftParts.set(last, leftParts.get(last) + toAdd);
                } else {
                    leftParts.add("" + toAdd);
                }

                // right
                List rightParts = parts.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());// shallow copy
                rightParts.add("" + toAdd);

                decompose(nextChar + 1, leftParts);
                decompose(nextChar + 1, rightParts);
            }
        }

    }

    class PartCount {
        String part;
        int count;

        public PartCount(String part, int count) {
            this.part = part;
            this.count = count;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[" + part + ", " + count + "]";
        }
    }

    class SortDecompositions implements Comparator> {

        public int compare(List a, List b) {
            // Here you can define what exactly means "taking up least space".
            return countChars(a) - countChars(b);
        }

        private int countChars(List listPc) {
            int count = 0;
            for (PartCount pc : listPc) {
                count += pc.part.length();
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using KMP alogorthm longest prefix which is also suffix
Steps:

1. iterate the string "ABCABCDEDEDEF" and construct lps array for the string. The values in the array will be
   0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   This lps array gives the number of times the prefix is repeated in the string.
   In the above case it is repeated only one time. Considering the actual prefix number of times will be 2 it becomes ABC*2
2. Take the substring of the remaining string and repeat the step 1 till the end of the string.

I can provide you the code if needed. The worst time complexity will be O(n2)